# How to use react ecosystem with rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, webpack, react-rails

I just want to share with you an uncomfortable situation that I'm having right now and ask you for advice. It turns out that I'm developing a kind of old project by using rails 3.2 and ruby 2.0. Until now, as usual I've been creating the view layer with haml markup language. Recently I was assigned to implement a new set of UI requirements that seems to be a little complicated. So I was wondering if I could use the react library to do that. I'm using the [react-rails](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) gem to facilitate the integration and it works fine. But the problem comes in when I try to use a third party library like react-dropzone or react-modal or whatever react library. I have not been able to get it to work neither using rails-assets gems nor downloading directly the /dist files and require them with sprockets. Some of the errors that I get are:

> typeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '**webpack_require**(3).unstable_renderSubtreeIntoContainer')
>
> Can not find module 'react'

I don't know if I can easily setup a webpack server to compile these react libraries and then can be used along with react-rails and the specific version of rails 3.2. I've searched about the subject and I found the [webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) gem but it requires at least rails 4.2. I appreciate any comment or observation about what should I do.

Comment: Just separate the React frontend complete from the Rails app. Then there is no need to handle React within Rails. If you have a stand-alone React frontend app that connects to the backend via a well-defined JSON interface, then you can choose up-to-date tooling on that side, choose a simpler server setup (S3?). And upgrading the backend app to maintained  Rails version is easier too.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally solved my problem by using [react_on_rails](https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails) gem which allows an easy integration of React + Webpack + Rails, and also includes the server side rendering option.